# gcd(a,b)=d then show that gcd(a/d,b/d)=1 (without euclids lemma or bezout's theorem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving the problem $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then show that $\gcd\left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\right)=1$ (without Euclid's lemma or Bézout's theorem) then stumbled upon the fact that if we say
$$\gcd\left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\right)= k \tag{1}$$
then $a=kdn$ and $b=kdm$ then,
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(m,n) \, kd \tag{2}$$
but I seem to not be able to prove that $(1)$ holds. If this holds then from this it’s clear that $d = \gcd(m,n)\,kd$ then $\gcd(m,n) = \frac{1}{k}$

Since $k$ is an integer and $\gcd(m,n)$ is also an integer then only value of $k$ that satisfies such a relation is $k = 1$ then by $(1)$ our question is answered.

So the question here is if two numbers $a = A \cdot B$ and $b = M \cdot N$, then
is it true that,
$$\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(A,M) \cdot \gcd(B,N)?$$

Comment: **No.** Take $A = 3$, $B = 4$, $M = 2$ and $N = 2$. Then $\gcd(12,4) = 4 \neq \gcd(A,B) \gcd(M,N) = 2$.

Comment: yeah got that but what about (2) ??

Comment: An other simpler way to prove that if $(a,b)=d$ then $(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$ is the following:
Since $(a,b)=d$,we know that there are $x_1,y_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax_1+by_1=d$.

Then, $(\frac{a}{d})x_1+(\frac{b}{d})y_1=1 (*)$ , $\frac{a}{d}, \frac{b}{d} \in \mathbb{Z}$

From this relation,we see that $(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$,because let's suppose that it is not true.

Then it will be $(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=\delta>1$.

Comment: But then,from the relation $(*)$, since $\delta$ divides the left part of the equation ($(\frac{a}{d})x_1+(\frac{b}{d})y_1$) , it will also divide the right one,that is equal to $1$,so $\delta \mid 1$,that is a contradiction.
So,we conclude that it must be: $(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$.

Comment: this is probably the best way but it says without bezout's lemma ie  without  , a x + b y = d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b>0$, $d=(a,b)$. Let $a'=ad^{-1},b'=bd^{-1}$. Suppose that $e\mid a',b'$. Then $de\mid a,b$, so $de\mid (a,b)=d$. This means $e\mid 1$. It follows that $(a',b')=1$.

Comment: Thanks this is probably the best ans!!

Answer (score 5):

If $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)=d$ then we know that $a=md$ and $b=nd$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $d$ contains all the factors that $a$ and $b$ have in common, we know that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Therefore:

$\mathrm{gcd}\left(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}\right)=\mathrm{gcd}\left(\frac{md}{d},\frac{nd}{d}\right)=\mathrm{gcd}\left(m,n\right)=1$

Answer (score -2):

Proof: Before starting with the proof proper, we should observe that although a/d and b/d have the appearance of the functions, in fact, they are integers because d is a divisor both of a and of b. Now, knowing that [gcd(a, b) = d](http://mathematicssolution.com), it is possible to find integers x and y such that d = ax + by. Upon dividing each side of this equation by d, we obtain the expression 
1 = (a/d)x + (b/d)y
Because a/d and b/d are integers, an appeal to the theorem is legitimate. The conclusion is that a/d and b/d are relatively prime.   (Proved)

Comment: Did you mean 'rationals' where you said 'have the appearance of the functions'?